# Create sine function with random increase in phase

Tags: functions, random

I am trying to simulate a signal that randomly increases its phase, so far I have tried two thing but neither worked. I usually use matlab but I want to learn some *Mathematica* so I thought I would try this in *Mathematica*.

My first try was

```
times = Table[i, {i, 0, 2, 0.05}];
function[source_, t_][fiIN_] := 
    With[{fi = fiIN + 0.01*RandomReal[]},source*(1 + Sin[2 Pi*t + fi])];
```

Where I wanted to feed `fi` back into `fiIN` for each subsequent `t` value (in the list `times`). I did not know how to makes this work though so I went on with my second try:

```
fiupdate[fi_] := fiupdate[fi - 1] + 0.01*RandomReal[]; 
fiupdate[1] = 0;
fitimes = Range[Length[times]];
```

However this function does not remember the value of `RandomReal[]` for the earlier steps, so `fiupdate[10]` could be smaller than `[9]` or `[8]`. Also when using this function I get an error:

```
fis = fiupdate[fitimes];
$RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded
```

Im not sure how to make this work. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem can be reduced to creating an increasing function, `phase`, and then use `Sin[t + phase[t]]`.

Here is one way to do this by interpolating a sorted list of random numbers:

```
tmax = 40;
phase = Interpolation[Sort[RandomReal[10, tmax]]];
Plot[phase[t], {t, 1, tmax}]
Plot[{Sin[t], Sin[t + phase[t]]}, {t, 1, tmax}]
```

[image: plots]

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice and clear implementation.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `Sin[t + phase[t]]` where `phase[t]` is `Interpolation` of a random process.

This random process can be implemented by `Accumulate`

```
tmin = 0;
tmax = 10;
dt = 0.1;

phase = Interpolation[
   Transpose@{ Range[tmin, tmax, dt], 
     Accumulate@RandomReal[1.0, Floor[(tmax - tmin)/dt + 1]]}, 
   InterpolationOrder -> 1];

Plot[phase[t], {t, tmin, tmax}]
```

[image]

or by `PoissonProcess`

```
phase = Interpolation[
   RandomFunction[
     PoissonProcess[1/dt], {0, Floor[(tmax - tmin)/dt + 1]}]["Path"], 
   InterpolationOrder -> 1];

Plot[phase[t], {t, tmin, tmax}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I like the way you show two equivalent techniques.

Answer (score 7):

One way will be to use `Nest` or something like that...

```
tmax = 20;
times = Table[i, {i, 0, tmax, 0.05}];
fi = With[{dist = .8}, (*here you can control how big jump is possible between phases*)
     NestList[RandomReal[{#, # + dist}] &,RandomReal[],-1 + Length@times]];
phaseIncrese =Transpose@{times, (1 + Sin[2 Pi*#1 + #2]) & @@@ (Transpose[{times,fi}])};
With[{(f = Interpolation@phaseIncrese)},
     Plot[{1 + Sin[2 Pi*t], f[t]}, {t, 1, 4}, Frame -> True]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is a very nice answer! A bit too advanced for me though. Most of your code I dont understand yet (a lot of the # and @ operators). Thats why I opted to accept ssch`s answer. But if a more advanced user is looking for the same thing I was they will probably benefit from your answer.

Comment: @Leo that's fine! I will elaborate the meaning when I am free. You can check my update later.